# Moving to next question when failing to receive a response

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es

We had a developer to come up with a prototype for a bot for bookkeeping questions and we understand that the bot is not perfect. Our biggest challenge was to ensure that after 2-3 failed attempts for the bot to receive an appropriate response, the bot moves on to the next question and that's it. Our previous developer claimed that it's not possible, is that true or not? Currently the bot just gives up after a couple of attempt and that's it.

I am not a tech person and I would really appreciate some help on this.

Hypothetical example of the ideal scenario:

Q: What accounting software do you use?
A: askdnjsajld

Q: Didn't get that. What accounting software do you use?
A: asdkjnajksdn

Q: I am sorry, didn't get that. Let's move on to the next question... When would you like to receive your financials? 
A: month-end

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, although the exact details of how you do this depend on how you're handling responses from the user in the first place.

The most important thing to keep in mind to handle this, however, is to remember that Intents represent *what the user says* and not how you handle it *or how you reply*.

That last bit gives the simplest answer to your question - you can, of course, reply however you want the bot to reply after each round. It sounds like you were able to implement logic that says if it got a result it didn't want - you can extend that to add a counter that just uses the next question as its reply after a number of tries.

The more difficult part is to make sure that you know what question the user is replying to, and to make sure you capture the right value in case they try to go back and answer a previous question.

The general solution to this problem is twofold:

- Have one Intent that accepts the direct answer to the question you're currently on, but have it triggerable only with certain Input Contexts being set. Then set that Context to be valid when you ask the question, and remove the Context when the question is answered.
- Have other Intents that specifically respond to how the user might phrase the question if they were going back to answer it.

For example, if you have asked "What software do you use?" you might set the Context "ask-software-used". You would then have two Intents:

- One with an Input Context of "ask-software-used" that accepts just valid software names.
- Another with no Input Context, but which might have training phrases such as

  - "I'm using XXXX software"
  - "We are working with the XXXX package"

once the user does answer the question, clear the "ask-software-used" Context, ask the next question, and set its Context.

You can also use this to keep track of how many times you've had to repeat the question, waiting for an answer. If that counter hits the limit, do the same thing: clear the Context, ask the next question, and set its Context.

Comment: Thank you so much, that’s super helpful!

Comment: Great! If an answer helps, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.